# How to deserialize empty string as a null value in java?

Tags: java, jackson

I am coming to a problem where I am trying to deserialize empty string as null value with my code below. is there a way to deserialize it properly.  I created a class `EmptyStringDeserializer` but I got stuck creating the custom deserializer. Below you can find my `EmptyStringDeserializer` to see what I did wrong.

Comment: Have you debugged your application to check what JSON is actually incoming?

Comment: yes sir - I have debugged already.

Comment: could you provide me an example JSON so I can run the code on  my machine?

Comment: please see updated question.

Comment: thanks, I will check that at home this evening. BTW are you sure this is correct JSON for your use case? You define columns in the annual section that are not present in your JSON, as "MAXIMUM_ANNUAL" and I do not see an IgnoreUnknown annotation

Comment: yes it is. I also I have 3 instance showing - i just showed one instance of it .

Comment: But, you think my `EmptyStringDeserializer` class, looks good?

Comment: Okey as stated I will check that in about 3 hours and give you feedback how to make it work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could enable [`ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT) in your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

---

Alternatively, you could define a custom deserializer:

```java
public class CustomStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
            throws IOException {

        String value = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

And register it to a module in your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(String.class, new CustomStringDeserializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

This deserializer will be used to deserialize all strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you want the declaration of the objectMapper to be in my class `JobSerializer` ,right?

Comment: @VeeA No, that's not what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@JsonDeserialize` should be on field level not on class level. Add on every String field.

Comment: Hi. Please explain or show what do you mean as field level?

Comment: @Column(name = "MOU")
@JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyStringDeserializer.class)
public String mou;

Comment: @VeeA you need to put the annotation above your class variable that should be deserialitzed with your custom deserializer:
@JsonDesirialize(using=...)
private String XY

Thats how I made it work for me yesterday

Comment: this is what I did. `@JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyStringDeserializer.class)
    public String jobClassTitle;`

Comment: and it did not work. and I do need the jSON Serialzie too as well.